# Define setter for hash member in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, setter

I have hash defined like this:

```
var props = {
    id: null,
    title: null,
    status: null
};
```

I'd like to define setter for status field (and only for it) doing it as following:

```
props.__defineSetter__("status", function(val){
    //Checking correctness of val...
    status = val;
});
```

But it doesn't work :(
So, what's the right way to do it?

Comment: Are you aware that only Mozilla implements setters/getters at the moment?

Comment: And Chrome, and Safari, and probably Opera. IE, as usual, does not.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, you need to use

```
this.status = val;
```

Otherwise you are just setting an unrelated global variable `status` equal to `val`.

And as already noted, setters/getters are not implemented in IE.

Also, I'm not sure about how wise it is to have a setter that is the same name as the property it sets. Not sure if this will result in a conflict, but it does seem like a bad idea yes? Ideally the variable that would be set should be hidden in a closure

```
var props = {
  id: null,
  title: null
};

(function() {

  var status;
  props.__defineSetter__("status", function(val){
    //Checking correctness of val...
    status = val;
  });

  props.__defineGetter__('status', function() { return status; });

}());
```

This way, `status` is fully protected from direct access, which is the point of using setters and getters.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is what MooGoo has pointed out. But also, you can not assign a property setter to an object using the same name as an existing variable in the object.

So your code would have to be something arround this:

```
var props = {
    id: null,
    title: null,
    hStatus: null,
};

props.__defineSetter__("status", function(v){
    this.hStatus = v;
});

props.__defineGetter__("status", function(){
    return this.hStatus;
});
```

[edit]
Yeah, MooGoo eddited his answer faster then time time I took to write this 8(.

Comment: These things happen, +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
props.__setStatus__ = function(val) {
    // Check correctness of val
    this.status = val;
}
```

Usage:

```
props.__setStatus__('Alive');
```